# Template is re-rendered even though there is no data change

Tags: meteor

I'm struggling with an issue that I will explain giving a simple demo.

There's following very simple document in `People` Collection.

```
{  
    "_id" : "vxmLRndHgNocZouJg",  
    "fname" : "John" ,  
    "nicks" : [ "Johnny" , "Jo"]  
}
```

Now let's consider following templates. Basically I display username and a list of nicknames with input field for adding more nicknames.

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> name}}<br/>
  {{> nicks}}
</body>

<template name="name">
    <input type="text" value="{{fname}}"/>
</template>

<template name="nicks">
    {{#each nicks}}
        <div>{{this}}</div>
    {{else}}
        no nicks yet
    {{/each}}
    <input type="text" name="nicks"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</template>
```

My client javascript code is as follows:

```
Template.name.fname = function() {
    return People.findOne({"fname" : "John"},{
        transform : function(doc) {
            return doc.fname;
        }
    });
}

Template.name.rendered = function() {
  console.log('Template "name" rendered!');
}

Template.nicks.nicks = function() {
  var john = People.findOne({"fname" : "John"});
  if(john) return john.nicks;
}
Template.nicks.events({
'click input[type="submit"]' : function () {
  var johnId = People.findOne({"fname" : "John"})._id; // demo code
  People.update(johnId,{
      $addToSet : {
          nicks : $('input[name="nicks"]').val()
      }
  })
}
});
```

My problem is that after adding nickname (update of `nicks` field in a document) template `name` is re-rendered (I know because I console.log it). When I query `People` collection to provide data for `name` template I use `transform` option so changes in `nicks` field shouldn't have impact on `name` template.

Meteor docs supports this:

> Cursors are a reactive data source. The first time you retrieve a cursor's documents with fetch, map, or forEach inside a reactive computation (eg, a template or autorun), Meteor will register a dependency on the underlying data. Any change to the collection that changes the documents in a cursor will trigger a recomputation.

Why template `name` is re-rendered then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is re-rendered because you change the `People` collection.

When you alter the `People` collection, Meteor automatically assumes that everything that it provides data to needs to be recalculated. (Which your `name` template does via `Template.name.fname`.

Even though you transform the output of the cursor, the `People` collection has changed in some way. The query is done before the transform is used, in other words, its not the transform that is looked at but the whole collection.

Meteor thinks that perhaps your document with `{'fname':'John'}` may have some other field that might have changed and it needs to requery it to check (which the `nicks` field has been altered). The transform is then applied after the requery.

Your HTML might not actually change at this point, only if the cursor returns something different will the html be changed.

If it becomes an issue in any scenario (i.e forms being cleared or DOM being changed when it shouldn't be) you can use the `{{#isolate}} {{/isolate}}` blocks to ensure that only everything inside them is re-rendered and nothing outside.